# OpenGL glm::perspective() doesn't work properly, objects aren't 3d

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glm-math

This is my game loop. I know I don't need to declare these variables twice, but I did them just in case:

```
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {


        GLfloat currentFrame = glfwGetTime();
        deltaTime = currentFrame - lastFrame;
        lastFrame = currentFrame;


        glfwPollEvents();


        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
        glm::mat4 view;
        view = glm::rotate(view, 50.0f, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
        glm::mat4 projection;
        projection = glm::perspective(-45.0f, float(WIDTH / HEIGHT), 0.1f, 100.0f);

        GLint modelLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "model");
        GLint viewLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "view");
        GLint projLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "projection");

        glUniformMatrix4fv(viewLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));
        glUniformMatrix4fv(projLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection));

        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glm::mat4 model;
        model = glm::scale(model, glm::vec3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f));
        glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
        glBindVertexArray(0);

        glUseProgram(shaderProgram2);
        glm::mat4 view2;
        view2 = translate(view2, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -0.6f));

        GLint modelLoc2 = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram2, "lightmodel");
        GLint viewLoc2 = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram2, "lightview");
        GLint projLoc2 = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram2, "lightprojection");

        glm::mat4 model2;
        model2 = glm::scale(model2, glm::vec3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f));


        glUniformMatrix4fv(viewLoc2, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view2));
        glUniformMatrix4fv(projLoc2, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection));

        glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLoc2, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model2));

        glBindVertexArray(lightVAO);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
        glBindVertexArray(0);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }
```

And this the output:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzmfc.jpg

I'm not clear if glm::perspective() input should be radians or degrees, but I tried both and they all gave the same zoomed-in, non-3D result. I don't know what I'm doing wrong here. I'm doing these according to [this](https://learnopengl.com/#!Lighting/Colors) tutorial. My body of code looks exactly like the tutorial's save for a few classes that I created myself. What could be the problem here?

Comment: try `float(WIDTH) / HEIGHT` instead of `float(WIDTH / HEIGHT)`

Comment: Newer versions of `glm` take radians for `glm::perspective()`. You are passing degrees and for some reason a negative angle.

Comment: @Tulon: didn't fix the issue. I have to ramp it up to 90 degrees. It fixed it and now I see the second rectangle, but I don't see the first rectangle and it's not 3D either.

Comment: @Tulon: I fixed the issue. It's drawing the first one they're just overlapping. But neither of them are in 3D: https://imgur.com/a/trQTA 

Do you know why?

Comment: I've no idea what you mean by "But neither of them are in 3D"

Comment: Could you tell us what exactly you are rendering? Looks like two black rectangles and a white cube to me (which seem to be perspectively distorted).